# geom_smooth moves based on scale_y_continuous limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a plot of stopping distance vs. speed, for the `cars` data, smoothed.

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x=cars$speed,y=cars$dist)) + 
+   scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
+   scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits=c(-20,125)) + geom_smooth()
```

[image]

Note that the grey confidence interval goes up to about 112.5.

Now suppose I want to crop some of the unused area at the top of the plot, by changing the y-axis limits.

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x=cars$speed,y=cars$dist)) + 
+   scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
+   scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits=c(-20,116)) + geom_smooth()
Warning message:
Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_smooth).
```

Note the warning message; I'll come back to that.

[image]

See how the grey confidence interval now only goes up to about 104?
I suspect that is because the `geom_smooth` function discarded one of the original data points because it is outside of the range, and that changed the smoothing calculation. (Indeed, one of the stopping distances is 120.) I assume that's what the warning message meant.

How can I work around this? The wasted space in the original plot isn't much of a problem, but with my own data, I would have a huge amount of wasted space. Do I need to calculate the smoothing formula separately, and then plot that using `geom_ribbon` and `geom_line`?

There is an option for `geom_smooth`, `fullrange=TRUE`, that you can use if your x-axis limits don't include all of the data. But that doesn't work here, and there isn't a `fulldomain=TRUE` option.

---

EDIT: The *problem* described here is different from the one described in [ggplot2: geom_smooth confidence band does not extend to edge of graph, even with fullrange=TRUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344065) (even though the solution is essentially the same). That problem is about the grey confidence interval being *cut off*. This problem is about the smoothing line and the interval being *changed* by the axis limits. I don't know that someone searching for a solution to this problem would be likely to recognise that the other problem has the same solution; it was only by chance that I did.

Comment: @beetroot I've added an explanation of why this problem is different.

Comment: I really don't see a difference big enough to justify leaving this open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limits in scales() first set the values outside of the limits to missing and then calculates the geom.

Limits in coords() first calculates the geoms and then plots only the information within the limits.

See http://rpubs.com/INBOstats/zoom_in for some reproducible examples.

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution here (even though the problem described is different, the solution is the same): 
[ggplot2: geom_smooth confidence band does not extend to edge of graph, even with fullrange=TRUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344065/ggplot2-geom-smooth-confidence-band-does-not-extend-to-edge-of-graph-even-with)

The solution is to use `coord_cartesian` to constrain the y-axis, instead of `scale_y_continuous(..., limits=...)`. We can even get rid of the nonsensical portion that goes into negative stopping distances.

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x=cars$speed,y=cars$dist)) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,116)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) + geom_smooth()
```

[image]

For more information on the difference between using scales or co-ordinate systems to control the plot limits, see
http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/coord_cartesian.html