# ggplot: geom_smooth() lines don't extend to left edge at x=0 with log10 transformation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `geom_smooth()` with ggplot but the lines generated by it don't quite reach the edge at x = 0. I found a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344065/ggplot2-geom-smooth-confidence-band-does-not-extend-to-edge-of-graph-even-with), but that one only has weirdness with the confidence bands reaching the edges. I'm pretty sure this has to do with the log10 transformation; removing it fixes the issues, but switching the order around (`geom_smooth()` after the `scale_x_continuous()`) or adding limits doesn't fix the issue. I've also included the ggplot call and the data.frame (sorry about the redactions; I was too lazy to actually go in and change the data).

[image]

```
ggplot(finalDF) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = foldBackground, color = strain), size = 1.3) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = x, y = foldBackground, color = strain), fullrange = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10') +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442")) + 
  theme_pubr()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `expand` argument in y and x scale:

```
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10', expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

Comment: It works, thanks! What exactly does `expand` do? The doc around it is kinda confusing, thanks again.

Comment: By default `ggplot` adds some extra space before the axis. the expand argument is used to control that space. when we set expand = c(0,0), we removed that space. Try with something like `expand = c(0, 10)` and `expand = c(10, 0)` to see the effect on x and y axis.